# Is it possible to change an output of a partially signed transaction?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, smartcontracts

In step 5 of the procedure described in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Smart_Property#Theory, the buyer creates a partially signed transaction. Will the seller be able to change an output prior to signing and broadcasting - and thus returning the token to an output he may redeem himself?

Answer (score 2):

In one word: **no**. Changing tx output after signing makes existing signature invalid.

( There are some special cases, like signature hash type SIGHASH_SINGLE or SIGHASH_NONE, but we assume that the buyer uses correct signing SIGHASH_ALL )

Comment: There's nothing more correct about SIGHASH_ALL than other signature types.